# Woman out to get revenge on men who killed her kid

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching this movie when I was a little kid (though, I probably shouldn't have). The title had something to do with dragons, but the movie itself did not.

The movie was about a woman who was shopping with her young son, possibly for a Halloween costume, when a group of masked men came in, and one of them shot and killed the kid.

The remainder of the movie was about the woman seeking out revenge. She may have been wearing a short blue wig at one point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of [*Blue Tiger*, from 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Tiger_%28film%29). A mother and her son are out shopping for a Halloween mask when her son is killed by accident during a gang hit by Yakuza/Japanese Mafia. One of the gangsters has a tiger tattooed on his chest. The rest of the movie follows her descent into the underworld of the Japanese mafia as she becomes obsessed with finding the gangster and getting revenge. Virginia Madsen played the mother.

The "tiger" tattoos in the film look kind of like dragons and the plot fits which is why I think this might be your film.

A trailer for the film is available on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrp-OxSJYTU)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been driving me nuts forever. The tattoo must have been why I thought 'dragon' was in the title.

Comment: Damn, I've been looking for this exact same movie for years myself. Thanks a lot :D